# up; into the following state?

Tags: vocabulary

> to end **up** in the army ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/end?s=t) *verb*, end #30)

‘*End*’ denotes ‘*reach or arrive at a final condition, circumstance, or goal (often followed by up)*'. Then if it, *end up*, is followed by prepositional phrases, participles, adjectives, does ‘***up***’ denote ‘***into the following state***’?

Comment: [*Where will it all end?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Where+will+it+all+end%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) *It will all end in tears* (never ***up*** there). The optional preposition ***up*** mainly helps to differentiate contexts like *"His career started in Australia, but ended **up** in America"*. Where without the explicit phrasal verb form *to end up = [eventually] arrive at*, one might be tempted to mistakenly draw the inference that his career *is already over* at time of speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it helps to view the *up* as having its own denotation here. The meaning of *end up* is certainly related to the meanings of various other verb-particle idioms with *up* (such as *wind up*: "we wound up talking for hours"; and *turn up*: "he turned up missing"), but ultimately, they are idioms, and best viewed as complete wholes.

Syntactically, too, it is *end up* + <adverbial>, not *end* + *up* <adverbial>; for example, one can say "Where did he end up?", but never *"Up where did he end?"

The opposite of *end up*, incidentally, is *start out*: "he started out in the Army". It works much the same way.